# How to quit ASP.NET Kestrel web server on a Mac

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm running a simple MVC app generated by Yeoman on my Mac using the ASP.NET vNext K runtime. I can run `k kestrel` from the project directory, and everything boots up and runs just fine. However, when I hit Ctrl+C (or any other key combination I've tried), the server doesn't quit. I have to close the terminal window to get the server to shut down. What am I missing?

Comment: Same solution applies if you start site using `dnx . kestrel`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It turns out that simply hitting "Enter" exits kestrel cleanly, without the need to kill the mono-sgen process afterward. There is [a github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/26) on the Kestrel repo asking to make this more obvious.

Comment: On Ubuntu I seem to have to press "Enter" and follow it with CTRL+C

Comment: Justi using 'Enter' worked fine for me on OS X, although there was a short delay before the mono-sgen process came down, after terminal prompt returned.

Answer (score 45):

If simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't work for you, try the following in the terminal window where you're running Kestrel:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> to suspend the process.
2. Type: `kill %1`.

Answer (score 8):

Hit Ctrl+Z, then you will need to kill the mono-sgen process to be able to run 'k kestrel' again with the same IP:PORT (If someone knows a better way please let us know)

After "Ctrl+Z" type "ps" to list your processes and find the PID for "/Users/YOU/.kre/packages/KRE-mono45-x86.1.0.0-alpha4", for example: "123456", then type "kill 123456".

UPDATE: I tried to use 'killall mono-sgen' but doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any processes open simply pressing "Enter" wont work on a mac. However if you use the example from UnraisedCesar and kill all your processes. Then restart the k kestrel you should be able to press "Enter" (if this is the only one of these processes running) and it will end properly.